# Find the angle CDE given two vectors OA and OB and ratios

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

**You are given the vectors OA = $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}$ and OB = $\begin{pmatrix} 66 \\ -22 \end{pmatrix}$ The point C divides OA in the ratio 1:2. The point D divides AB in the ratio 3:4. The point E divides OB in the ratio 6:5. Find the angle CDE giving your answer to the nearest whole degree?**

I found vectors CD, DE and CE and used the cosine rule to find the angle which should have been 152 degrees to the nearest degree however this is not marked as correct. [image]

Comment: I haven't checked every last detail but your approach looks fine to me - and very nicely laid out.  Either you have made a numerical slip somewhere or your teacher is looking for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Vector OC is $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2 \end{pmatrix}$ not $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\3 \end{pmatrix}$ resulting in an angle of 150 degrees to the nearest degree.
[image]